# Can I cp to stdout/pipe?

Tags: pipe, cp, stdout

Ok, it might sound weird but bear with me. I want to use `cp` to copy content of my block device, and I want to pipe it to `gzip` to compress it on the fly. Can I do this with `cp`? I know I can use `dd`, but I'm just wondering if it would be possible to make such a pipeline starting with `cp`.

Comment: It's completely pointless to use `cp` instead of directly `gzip` (or Uuocat), but if you really want it, and have a shell like bash or ksh93, `cp input >(gzip -c >output.gz)`.

Comment: `cp` is the wrong tool. That's a bit like trying to eat soup with a fork...

Comment: @roaima I know, but it's fascinating and very informative what are people coming up with :) .

Comment: If you omitted `cp` from your requirement entirely it would make more sense: `gzip </dev/sda >sda.img.gz`.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `cp` since `cp` would not under normal circumstances write to standard output, but you could use `cat`:

```
cat device-file | gzip -c >some-output-file
```

In this case, it makes sense to use `cat` since you probably need to prefix it with `sudo` or similar command to access the device from an unprivileged user's shell session.  If you're in a root shell (for whatever reason, and there's almost never a reason),

```
gzip -c <device-file >some-output-file
```

would have worked too.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Sorry, I don't have `/proc` on my system, but if you replace it with `/dev/stdout` which looks a bit more portable, then the output would indeed appear on standard output. I will amend the answer, but I won't suggest using `cp` since using `cp` as a part of a pipeline in that way is, IMHO, a misuse of that utility.

Comment: I agree that using `cp` as a part of a pipeline is usually not the Right Thing. (Usually, because I have done `… | cp --sparse=always /dev/stdin ./some-file` for good reason.)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski In this case, the output is piped to `gzip`, which means any holes in the data would be replaced by zeros, and then compressed. Creating sparse files requires that the utility is writing to a file, not a pipe. You could therefore not use that trick with `cp` unless it was placed last in a pipeline.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm just being strict. I opposed "never" because there are ways to do it. I agreed with you and said "usually". The example with `--sparse` is just to justify "usually" (I mean: why not "always"?) and has nothing to do with piping to `gzip`.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a named pipe and copy your device into that:

```
mkfifo /tmp/mypipe
cp device-file /tmp/mypipe
```

then open another shell where you start gzip parallelly to read from the pipe and write to the output file:

```
gzip </tmp/mypipe >outfile.gz
```

When they are finished, you can delete the named pipe

```
rm /tmp/mypipe
```